# Magento Checkout Methods list

Tags: magento-1.4

Is there a way to see the methods lists that is being called in the shopping cart view.

```
<ul class="checkout-types">
    <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
        <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This code is in the views anywhere the "Proceed to Checkout" button shows up but my Paypal Express button isn't in the list. I can trace it back to the Block abstract but then the code looses me (ie what calls setChild to make 'methods' a child and to give it a block?).